# Java array loop iteration

Tags: java, arrays

I have a function of type:
I can iterate the array as follows. (Standard example)
arrays can be looped over and the elements returned to a variable x as follows.

```
public Map<String, String> (Object ... args)
{
   . . .
   for( Object x : args); // do stuff
   . . .
   dummyUsexAndPrint(x); // just demonstrating that we can now use x
                         // x will vary on each loop iteration.
}
```

My objective is to make key value pairs out of the array while not doing any arithmetic.
Can we iterate over a loop "two by two"?
Something like this ---->

```
public Map<String, String> (Object ... args)
{
    . . .
    for( Object X : args, Object Y : args) {
        globalMap.put(X,Y); // using X and Y now, instead of just "x"         

                            //in the previous case
    }
    . . .
}
```

The first case matches the pattern `(a_1, a_2 ...).`
While, I need to match the pattern `(a_1, a_2, a_3 ...)`
and extract a_1 and a_2 on each run of the loop.

Is this kind of pattern matching possible in Java?
I have not come across any such examples, Just wish to verify.

Edit:

Suppose we have an array [1,2,3,4,5,6].

A simple loop like

```
for (int x : array) { ...}
```

will give me x as
1
2 
3
4
5
6

What I want is get 2 values at a time.

```
for (int x,y : array) { ... }
```

1 2

3 4

5 6

where the left hand value is x and the right hand value is y.

Edit 2:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i == array.length - 1; i += 2)
{
x = array[i];
y = array[i + 1];
print(x, y);
}
```

Does this clear up?

Edit: Seems like there is no way to escape the arithmetic. I was hoping that my array iteration could be done without doing the arithmetic, and it would throw me an exception (so that I do not have to check for even/odds).

The contract would have been for the loop to pick 2 members at a time and loop over. If there were no members left, the contract was fulfilled, if there was one member left, the contract of decomposing two values at a time is violated and an exception thrown.

No such luck, in some languages it is possible to match patterns directly, instead of writing primitive loops. I'm new to Java, so was exploring.

Comment: Can you provide some more information, e.g what you've tried so far, example input with expected output etc. Its unclear what you're asking for help with

Comment: I found it perfectly clear

Comment: you cant get different values from Object X and Object Y, and please show us some code you have tried and the expected input and output. I am not sure what you really want to achieve with this and what you want to do. make things simple and simplified

Comment: @gbtimmon what does lel want because clearly you cant get different values from the Object X  and Object Y

Comment: If you want to iterate over a grid of values, just use two for loops. I.e. `for (Object X : args) { for (Object y : args) { ... } }`

Comment: Seems like most people aren't familiar with pattern matching? All I am trying to do is  to iterate the array two values each loop iteration, instead of just the first value.

Comment: @lel No, it's just not clear what you were asking.

Comment: Just use a standard for loop and increment by 2.

Comment: @Jashaszun, I'm not sure I follow. won't the inner loop now run to completion? I'm not iterating a grid. It is a linear array.

Comment: @lel I'm not sure what you're asking then. When you say `// using X and Y now, instead of just "x"`, it makes me think that you want to iterate over args`, and then for each value, iterate again over the entire `args`. That's exactly what I just told you how to do. If not that, then you need to clarify your question.

Comment: @lel How is your Y different than your X, when they both iterate over args?

Comment: Just saw your edit, where did the last `6` come from, when your array only goes up to `5`?

Comment: they are not different. All I want is not to do the arithematic. I could do
@Jashaszun, just an example? 6 was there just to complete the set.

Comment: @lel, there's no way around doing the arithmetic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a Deque like this..

```
 import java.util.*;

 Deque<String> queue = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(new String[] { "1", "2", "3", "4" }));
 Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();
 for (int i = 0; i < queue.size(); i++)
    data.put(queue.pop(), queue.pop());
```

Or you can use an iterator like this in place of a for loop

```
while (queue.iterator().hasNext()) {
    data.put(queue.pop(), queue.pop());
}
```

And you have your map with data as you'd wanted. Let me know if that helps

Regards Douglas

Comment: Yes, this is a good alternative, if the language lacks the capability. A queue.pop on an empty queue would also lead to an exception. I'm still not happy about decomposing using queue.size(), but it seems to be unavoidable.
I can get my original data as queue.

Comment: wrap it in a try-catch

Comment: Yes, I want my code to throw an exception when it is not even, without having to put an if (length == even) check. Your code does that, and I'm happy with it.

Comment: Yes, this is good. Since it will just use references, creating a linked list out of an array should not be expensive, at least for moderately sized arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Both of these answers assume that the length of the collection is even (because, obviously, if it isn't, then you won't always have a `y` for each `x`).

For `T[] args`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i+=2) {
    T x = args[i];
    T y = args[i+1];

    // ... use x and y, e.g. System.out.println(x + " " + y);
}
```

For a general collection of `T`s:

```
boolean even = true;
T x = null;
for (T obj : args) {
    if (even) {
        x = obj;
    } else {
        T y = obj;

        // use x and y, e.g. System.out.println(x + " " + y);
    }
    even ^= true; // flip even
}
```

Comment: I was hoping that I could decompose the array into [head, next and tails] instead of just [heads and tails]. with exception thrown if any decomposition failed. Your answer is the way to go, I'll also have to write an exception to throw.

Comment: Don't you think `even = !even` is a bit more intuitive?

Comment: @shmosel Not really, they're about equal for me. One way I think of xor is `if right side is true, flip left, otherwise leave alone`. So `xor true` means `flip left`.

Answer (score 0):

This what you looking for:

```
for (int i = 0; i < args.length - 1; )
{
    int x = args[i];
    int y = args[++i];

    i++;

    System.out.println(x + " " + y);
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I do not wish to do! See my edit. I did state that I do not want to do the arithematic.

Comment: @lel: too bad.  There's no other way.